# Rank 2 bundles on $\mathbb P^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal E$ be an $SL(2)$-bundle on $\mathbb P^2$.
Assume that the restriction of $\mathcal E$ to any $\mathbb P^1$ is non-trivial.
Is it true that $\mathcal E$ is a direct sum of two line bundles?

Comment: In positive characteristic $2$, I believe that can fail (possibly you are interested only in characteristic $0$).  If you pullback the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^2$ by a Frobenius map, then the degree is even.  Thus, you can tensor with an invertible sheaf to make the determinant trivial.  Every line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ maps under Frobenius to a line (with different coefficients).  The restriction of $T_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ to a line is $\mathcal{O}(2)\oplus \mathcal{O}(1).$

Comment: Thanks. But what about characteristic 0?

Comment: The answer by @Sasha works in all characteristics.  If $E$ is a direct sum of $\mathcal{O}(-d)$ and $\mathcal{O}(d)$, then the second Chern class of $E$ equals $-d^2 c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))^2$ for the integer $d$.  Thus, for a rank $2$ locally free whose first Chern class is not such a negative square, $E$ cannot be a direct sum of invertible sheaves.

Comment: Note, that my previous comment also explains pullbacks of the tangent bundle.  For every morphism $f:\mathbb{P}^2\to \mathbb{P}^2$ with $f^*\mathcal{O}(1)\cong \mathcal{O}(2b)$ for an integer $b$ (whether or not $f$ is a Frobenius morphism), for $E=\mathcal{O}(-3b)\otimes f^*T_{\mathbb{P}^2}$, then $c_2(E)$ equals $3e^2 c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))^2$, and this is not of the form $-d^2c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))^2.$  Thus, $E$ is not a direct sum of two line bundles.

Comment: And is it obvious that $f^*T_{\mathbb P^2}$ is not a direct sum of two line bundles?

Comment: "And is it obvious ..."  That is what my previous comment is about.  By the Whitney sum formula, the second Chern class of $\mathcal{O}(-d)$ and $\mathcal{O}(d)$ equals $-d^2 c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))^2.$  However, for a morphism $f:\mathbb{P}^2\to \mathbb{P}^2$ of even "degree" $2b$, for the twist $E=\mathcal{O}(-3b)\otimes f^*T_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ that has zero first Chern class, the second Chern class is $3b^2 c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))^2.$  Since $+3b^2$ does not equal $-d^2$, the locally free sheaf $E$ is not a direct sum of two invertible sheaves.

Answer (score 4):

No. A simple counterexample is a nontrivial extension
$$
0 \to O(1) \to E \to I_x(-1) \to 0,
$$
where $x$ is a point and $I_x$ is its ideal sheaf.

EDIT: basics of Serre's construction.

First, note that
$$
Ext^1(I_x(−1),O(1)) \cong
Ext^2(O_x,O(1)) \cong 
H^0(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{E}\mathit{xt}^2(O_x,O(1))) \cong H^0(\mathbb{P}^2,O_x).
$$
Next, let us rewrite the defining sequence of $E$ as
$$
0 \to O(1) \to E \to O(-1) \to  O_x \to 0.
$$
Applying $\mathcal{H}\mathit{om}(-,O(1))$ to it, we get 
$$
0 \to O(2) \to  E^\vee(1) \to O \to \mathcal{E}\mathit{xt}^2(O_x,O(1)) \to \mathcal{E}\mathit{xt}^1(E,O(1)) \to 0.
$$
So, to check that $\mathcal{E}\mathit{xt}^1(E,O(1)) = 0$ and hence $E$ is locally free, it is enough to show that the map
$$
O \to \mathcal{E}\mathit{xt}^2(O_x,O(1)) \cong O_x
$$
is surjective. But by the above chain of isomorphisms, this map corresponds to the original extension class, hence is non-zero. And any non-zero map to $O_x$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain the notation? What is $I_x$?

Comment: @AlexanderBraverman: $I_x$ is the ideal of the point $x$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And why is such an extension locally free? (Sorry for the stupid questions)

Comment: @AlexanderBraverman: This is a special case of Serre's correspondence. Just note that $Ext^1(I_x(-1),O(1)) \cong Ext^2(O_x,O(1)) = H^0(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{E}\mathit{xt}^2(O_x,O(1))) \cong H^0(\mathbb{P}^2,O_x)$ and hence the class of the extension generates the sheaf $\mathcal{E}\mathit{xt}^2(O_x,O(1)) \cong O_x$.

Comment: Sorry, I am probably missing something basic: I understand why there is such a non-trivial extension, but why is it locally free? Doesn't it necessarily split in some neighbourhood of $x$?

Comment: These are basics of Serre's construction. You can find a good exposition in the book of Okonek-Schneider-Spindler. For convenience, I added some details to the answer.

Comment: @Sasha : are you sure $E$ does not split? On $\mathbb{P}^2$ a point $x$ is the complete intersection of two $\mathbb{P}^1$...

Comment: @Libli: No, $H^1(\mathbb{P}^2,E) \ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at $T_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ as Jason Starr suggests. We have the Euler exact sequence:

$$ 0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3 \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1) \rightarrow T_{\mathbb{P}^2} \rightarrow 0$$

Note that $\mathrm{Ext}^1(L_1,L_2) = 0$ for any two line bundles on $\mathbb{P}^2$. Hence, if $T_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ splits as direct sum of line bundles (say $L_1 \oplus L_2$), we have:

$$ \mathbb{C}^3 \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1) = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2} \oplus L_1 \oplus L_2,$$

which is clearly impossible. On the other hand, $T_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ is obviously $\mathrm{SL}_3$-homogeneous and by the normal exact sequence, the restriction of $T_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ to any $\mathbb{P}^1$ is $\mathcal{O}(1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(2)$, which is non-trivial.

You might be interested in the following result:

**Theorem** (Grauert-Mülich) : Let $E$ be a rank $2$, $\mu$-semi-stable vector bundle on $\mathbb{P}^2$ with $c_1(E) = 0.$ Then, for a generic line $l \subset \mathbb{P}^2$, the restriction $E|_{l}$ is trivial.

You could also have a look at this paper https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0099972 by Maruyama. In there he studies the singularities of the curve of lines $l \in \mathbb{P}^2$ such $E|_{l}$ is non-trivial.

**EDIT** I misunderstood what was meant by $\mathrm{SL}_2$-bundle. By $\mathrm{SL}_2$-bundle, you mean a rank-$2$ vector bundle with trivial first Chern class. So if your vector bundle does not restrict to the trivial bundle on the generic $\mathbb{P}^1$, then the Grauert-Mülich Theorem implies that it is not $\mu$-semi-stable. In particular, it has a destabilizing sub-line bundle.

It is not obvious to me that all unstable rank $2$ vector bundle on $\mathbb{P}^2$ do split, but that is perhaps true...

**EDIT(bis)** By proposition 4 of this paper : http://www.seminariomatematico.unito.it/rendiconti/67-1/15.pdf, a rank $2$-vector bundle (say $E$) on $\mathbb{P}^2$ with $c_1 = 0$ splits if and only if $h^1(E(-1)) = 0$.

Comment: You are right that $E$ should be unstable, and this precisely gives my example. The first $O(1)$ is the destabilizing subsheaf. You can replace it by $O(k)$ for any $k > 0$ (and then, of course, replace $I_x(-1)$ by $I_x(-k)$).

Comment: @Sasha : Ok. Sorry! I thought you had a misprint and that you wanted to write the Koszul complex twisted by $\mathcal{O}(1)$ (which would look like:

$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(-1) \rightarrow \mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O} \rightarrow I_x(1) \rightarrow 0)$$

But you are indeed considering something entirely different.